Back button doesn't go back a page but quits webview in FLUTTER
How to make this when I click the back button not close the web view but 1step go back from the web view
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class WebView extends StatefulWidget {
  const WebView({super.key});

  @override
  State<WebView> createState() => _WebViewState();
}

class _WebViewState extends State<WebView> {
  final controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse("https://youtube.com/"));
 //  
  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: WebViewWidget(
        controller: controller,
      ),
    );
  }
}


I want to know how to fix this

Does this answer your question? Using flutter webview as home and pressing back button closes Application

nope, I wanna go back in webview pages not screens

bool _isLoading = true;

appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('WebView'),
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            if (_controller != null) {
              _controller.goBack();
            }
          },
        ),
      ),


_controller.goBack(); use this to go bck within webview environment

No bro, i want in web view page 1step back
not web view to home page

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
